# On a CSS hover a button, can I change another div's child styling

Tags: html, css

When I hover on a button can I change another divs child style.

Html

```
<a href="#">   
  <div class="col-md-6 repair">
    <div class="imagehover">  
        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/restorarion.jpg" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-firstblock">REPAIR</button>
  </div>
 </a>
```

I tried these all below, but not working

```
.btn-firstblock:hover + .imagehover img{

-moz-transform: scale(1.08);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.08);
transform: scale(1.08);
opacity: 0.7;}
```

And

```
.btn-firstblock:hover ~ .imagehover img{

-moz-transform: scale(1.08);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.08);
transform: scale(1.08);
opacity: 0.7;}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no previous sibling selection in CSS, `+` is next sibling selector and `~` is again next but there could be another elements between. CSS is like waterflow, mean there is no backward action. This is why there is no previous sibling selector.

If you put the button before the `.imagehover` div it will work.

```css
.btn-firstblock:hover + .imagehover img{

-moz-transform: scale(1.08);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.08);
transform: scale(1.08);
opacity: 0.7;}
```

```html
<a href="#">   
  <div class="col-md-6 repair">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-firstblock">REPAIR</button>
    <div class="imagehover">  
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg" />
    </div>
    
  </div>
 </a>
```

**JQuery Solution**

If you need the button after the `.imagehover` div, you can use javascript like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn-firstblock').hover(function(){
    //mouseover
    $(this).prev().find('img').addClass('transform');
  },function(){
    //mouseout
    $(this).prev().find('img').removeClass('transform');
  })
})
```

```css
img.transform{

-moz-transform: scale(1.08);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.08);
transform: scale(1.08);
opacity: 0.7;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">   
  <div class="col-md-6 repair">
    <div class="imagehover">  
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-firstblock">REPAIR</button>
  </div>
 </a>
```